# OOP - Using a UIView to coordinate multiple subviews?

Tags: ios, oop, uiview

This is an Object Oriented Programming question:

So I am trying to build a UIView class that displays scatter plot. In my current implementation, I've created a datasource protocol that allows the chartView to ask for all the info it needs to plot the its data.

As it stands right now, when someone initializes the chartView and gives it a datasource, the chartview creates/manages several subviews: a 'dotsView' that displays all the data points, a scrollview to which the dotview is added (so it is scrollable), and a 'skeletonView' that sits in the background and displays other chart data like grid lines.

This system at first worked great, however, I decided that i'd like to animate changes to the points, and so i began to contemplate using a collectionView  in lieu of the 'dotsView' placed within the scrollview since it'll handle the animation for me. However, as a collectionview would require a delegate, datasource, layout object, etc, all the sudden my chartView seems to looks more and more like a controller and not a view.

Now here is my question: Is it the wrong approach to allow a UIView to coordinate/configure other UIViews, even if those UIViews are a fundamental requirement of the whole? On the one hand, I'd love to preserve the simplicity of my chartView's public interface (initialize the view, give it a datasource, and you're done). On the other hand, this chartView is really not a view anymore, its more like a controller. But I don't want a consumer of my chart to think/treat it like a controller, I want them to use it as a view.

Any thoughts? I'd love to hear the insights of others.

Thanks!

Comment: there is a `layoutSubviews` method in `UIView`

Comment: Point taken, but I think you're ignoring the nuance of the question. It's certainly not typical for a uiview to act as a uicollectionviewdatasource, for example.

Comment: Not typical, but not unheard of.  `UIPickerView` is the data source for its private `UITableView` subviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally fine for your `ChartView` to create a `UICollectionView`, use it as a subview, and be the data source and delegate for that subview, because the use of `UICollectionView` is an implementation detail of the `ChartView`.

Apple does this in `UIPickerView`.  Under the covers, a picker view creates one table view for each component, and the picker view makes itself the data source and delegate for each table view.  You can see in `UIPickerView.h` that it conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`.  You can check that it conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` at runtime with `+[NSObject conformsToProtocol:]`, or by using [`class-dump`](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump) on the UIKit framework.  Or you can just write a test app and poke around the view hierarchy.  The debugger command `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` will get you started.

`UIPickerView` is the only view subclass in the iOS SDK that I know of that acts as the data source and delegate for its subviews, but many other UIKit view classes create and manage their own subviews.  Examples:

- `UIScrollView` has private subviews for its scroll indicators.
- `UITableView` has private header, footer, section index, and row separator subviews.
- `UIButton` has a private `UILabel` to display its text and a private `UIImageView` to display its image.
- `UISegmentedControl` has private `UILabel` and `UIImageView` subviews.
- `UIProgressView` uses several private `UIImageView` subviews to display its parts.
- `UISlider` uses several private `UIImageView` subviews to display its parts.
- `UITextField` uses private `UIImageView` subviews.

Answer (score 0):

You answered you own question my friend: Is it the wrong approach to allow a UIView to coordinate/configure other UIViews -- YES!. Views should be casted by a Controller from an  organizational stand point IMHO. I would build a Charting Controller that can cast out single and composite views and kill two birds with one stone. The you could route urls to the controller from Ajax to change the data represented in the chart